# After changing field to read only, the form displays pk instead of value/ django forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

When I add this line of code to my form:

```
 borrower = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}))
```

The value of borrower is showing up as pk(id) instead of its real value. Any idea why is that?
The complete code for form:

```
class AmendLoan(ModelForm):
  borrower = forms.CharField(
      widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}))

  class Meta:
      model = BikeInstance

      fields = (
          'borrower',
          'frame_number',
          'due_back',
          'status'
      )
```

When I remove `readonly`, everything works fine, but I need this field to show up, but it cant be changed.

Comment: Do you really need it as a field? Could you alter the template and use {{ form.instance.borrower.name }}? Because now if you post, your form won't know it is a readonly field. So if I fake a POST with a borrower id in its body, then I could alter the borrower.

Comment: Can you post your `BikeInstance` model ?